# PHP producing a multidimensional associative array in desired format

Tags: php

I am trying to wrangle data into a desired format. Basically, I have a list in which a subset of the entities can have multiple values and need to be grouped and iterated over within the list.

Given the following example:

```
$entities = [
    0 => ['name' => 'a', 'type' => 'single'],
    1 => ['name' => 'b', 'type' => 'single'],
    2 => ['name' => 'c', 'type' => 'grouped'],
    3 => ['name' => 'd', 'type' => 'grouped'],
    4 => ['name' => 'e', 'type' => 'single'],
];

foreach ($entities as $entityKey => $entity) {

    if ($entity['type'] == 'single') {

        $array[] = ['name' => $entity['name']];
    }

    if ($entity['type'] == 'grouped') {

        // arbitrary number of items
        $items = [0 => 'apple', 1 => 'orange', 2 => 'banana'];

        foreach ($items as $itemKey => $item) {
            $array[] = ['name' => $entity['name']];
        }
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

How can I produce output: a, b, c, d, c, d, c, d, e, such that the entities of type 'grouped' are paired and iterated over before he next entity is inserted into the array. Specifically:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => c
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => d
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => c
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => d
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => c
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => d
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => e
        )

)
```

Comment: Are the ones with type `grouped` always supposed to show in the final array 3 times?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica - no the number of iterations is arbitrary depending on the number of "items"

Comment: But the number of items is also arbitrary? How is that determined?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica Result set of a database query. I abstracted the logic here to make it easier to articulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](https://tehplayground.com/NI91dHsnzr0paCQo) is a working solution for you.

```
$entities = [
    0 => ['name' => 'a', 'type' => 'single'],
    1 => ['name' => 'b', 'type' => 'single'],
    2 => ['name' => 'c', 'type' => 'grouped'],
    3 => ['name' => 'd', 'type' => 'grouped'],
    4 => ['name' => 'e', 'type' => 'single'],
];

$grouped = [];

foreach($entities as $entity){
    if($entity['type'] == 'grouped'){
        $grouped[] = $entity['name'];
    }
}

$f = 0;
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    if ($entity['type'] == 'single') {
        $array[] = ['name' => $entity['name']];
    }
    if ($entity['type'] == 'grouped') {
        $items = [0 => 'apple', 1 => 'orange', 2 => 'banana'];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
            foreach($grouped as $grouped_item){
                if($f < count($items)*2){
                    $array[] = ['name' => $grouped_item];
                }
                $f++;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($array);
```